# How to extract a value and use it in a future xpath query?

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I'm extracting the value of a node into a variable:

```
<xsl:variable name="UPC" select="//x:input[@name='field-keywords']/@value"/>
<xsl:value-of select="$UPC" />  <!-- This works! -->
```

Then I want to query another XML document for a node with the same value:

```
<xsl:value-of select="document('price_list.xml')/im_prices/row/UPC_Code[text()='$UPC']"/>
```

When I substitute $UPC for the actual value I find the node just fine, but when I use $UPC it doesn't work.

I haven't been able to work out how to extract the value to a variable and use it in a future xpath query.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Just remove the apostrophes -- in your expression you compare to the *literal* "$UPC":**

```
 <xsl:value-of select=
   "document('price_list.xml')
        /im_prices/row/UPC_Code[text()=$UPC]"/>
```

**There is something more to be said about this question**:

> I'm extracting the value of a node into a variable:
>
> ```
>  <xsl:variable name="UPC" select="//x:input[@name='field-keywords']/@value"/>
> ```

No, this doesn't "extract the value" -- the variable's value is a *set* of nodes, aka *nodeset*.

Also, do note that this nodeset in general has more than one node.

> ```
>  <xsl:value-of select="$UPC"/>  <!-- This works! -->
> ```

This outputs the string value of the *first* node contained in the variable `$UPC`.

```
Then I want to query another XML document for a node with the same value:

     <xsl:value-of select="document('price_list.xml')/im_prices/row/UPC_Code[text()='$UPC']"/>
```

Even if the apostrophes are removed, the above outputs the string value of the *first* of the `document('price_list.xml')/im_prices/row/UPC_Code` elements that has a text node child whose string value is equal to the string value of *one* of the nodes contained in the variable `$UPC`.

Comment: Thank you very much for the extended explanation, it helps a lot as I wasn't truly clear on a few key points you mentioned. the UPC_Code in this case is unique (my own knowledge) so taking the 1st such note is ok, but I appreciate you pointing out that it's entirely feasible that I would be skipping duplicate UPC_Code nodes.